# Trying to deploy database along with apk ,but force closing on the device

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I modified my sqliteopenhelper class as follows:

```
public class openingclass extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        public openingclass(Context c) {
            super(c,Db_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }
         public void createDataBase() {

                boolean dbExist;
                try {

                     dbExist = checkDataBase();


                } catch (SQLiteException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw new Error("database dose not exist");

                }

                if(dbExist){
                //do nothing - database already exist
                }else{

                    try {

                        copyDataBase();


                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                        throw new Error("Error copying database");

                    }
            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
                this.getReadableDatabase();


            }

            }

            /**
              * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
              * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
              */
            private boolean checkDataBase(){

            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

            try{
                String myPath = DB_PATH +"/"+ Db_NAME;

                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.
                throw new Error("database does't exist yet.");

            }

            if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

            }

            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
            }

            /**
              * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
              * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
              * This is done by transfering bytestream.
              * */
            private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{



                    //copyDataBase();
                    //Open your local db as the input stream
                    InputStream myInput = c1.getAssets().open(Db_NAME);

                    // Path to the just created empty db
                    String outFileName = DB_PATH +"/"+ Db_NAME;
                    File databaseFile = new File(DB_PATH);
                     // check if databases folder exists, if not create one and its subfolders
                    if (!databaseFile.exists()){
                        databaseFile.mkdir();
                    }

                    //Open the empty db as the output stream
                    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

                    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }

                    //Close the streams
                    myOutput.flush();
                    myOutput.close();
                    myInput.close();



            }



            @Override
            public synchronized void close() {

                if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

                super.close();

            }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
            String S = "create table " +
                    TABLE_NAME +
                    " (" +
                    TABLE_COL_MAIL + " text primary key," +
                    TABLE_COL_NAME + " text," +
                    TABLE_COL_PASS + " text," +
                    TABLE_COL_PHO + " text," +
                    TABLE_COL_ADD + " text," +
                    TABLE_COL_GEN + " text," +
                    TABLE_COL_DOB + " text" +
                    ");";
            arg0.execSQL(S);

            String S1 = "create table " +
                    SECOND_TABLE_NAME +
                    " (" +
                    TABLE_COL_USER + " text," +
                    TABLE_COL_PRODUCT + " text," +
                    TABLE_COL_QUANTITY + " integer" +
                    ");";
            arg0.execSQL(S1);




        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
```

I added the name and path of the database at class level as follows:

```
private final String DB_PATH="/data/data/com.example.shopkart/databases/";
    private final String Db_NAME = "dbshopkart.db";
```

The path is not correct as the application cannot see the database on running on the device.The LOGCAT is as follows:

```
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shopkart/com.example.shopkart.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: products: , while compiling: SELECT NAME from products  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3689)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: products: , while compiling: SELECT NAME from products  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1358)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1326)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at com.example.shopkart.datamanager.retrieveproducts(datamanager.java:218)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at com.example.shopkart.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)  
05-02 15:35:20.367: E/AndroidRuntime(7848):     ... 11 more
```

I posted this many times , and the problem seems to be the hard coded path. Can someone tell me how to set the path?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you call createDatabase() ?

Try putting this method inside your constructor. That way when you create a object of your openingClass it has to create the database before using it.

```
public openingclass(Context c) {
     super(c,Db_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
     createDataBase();
}
```

Comment: No, still getting the same force close.

Comment: I get that error when i create the database but don'y copy the data inside. Thus i don't have any tables. Or if just the name of the table you are SELECTING FROM is wrong.
Try doing a log inside copyDatabase() to see if its executed properly and copies every thing.

Comment: the name of the table cant be wrong as everything works fine on the AVD.

Comment: That may be because the data is already copied in the AVD. If you try to uninstall the application and do a fresh install it might give you the same error.
The problem is that it can't find the table you are looking for in the file that is created from your database class.

Comment: I removed a slash from the db path and got database doesnt exsist error